# Flutter Image_picker could not resolve all artifacts for configuration

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

after add `image picker` package in pubspec.yaml file.

I am try to run my flutter app but the run failed.

**The Error That I have when I am try to run flutter project :**

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':image_picker'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_picker:classpath'.
       > Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.3.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.3.0/crash-26.3.0.jar
       > Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.3.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.3.0/apkzlib-3.3.0.jar
       > Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.3.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.3.0/apksig-3.3.0.jar
       > Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.3.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.3.0/annotations-26.3.0.jar
       > Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.3.0/databinding-common-3.3.0.jar
       > Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.3.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.3.0/baseLibrary-3.3.0.jar
    > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
       > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':image_picker' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
       > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

---

### pubspce.yaml dependencies :

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      # adobe_xd: ^0.1.4
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      google_fonts_arabic: ^1.1.7
      scoped_model: ^1.0.1
      http: ^0.12.2
      shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
      flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
      image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
```

---

### the build.gradle content :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
     google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
     google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try this,hope this works.if you are using android  studio open android folder with in flutter project  then run clean project  then run rebuild project @mohammad al lababedi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Check that dependencies installed well
If ok
2-Try to redebuge the app
If not
2-Try to install Flutter SDK developer version instead of stable

### *edit*

3- in terminal execute this commends

```
flutter clean
```

to clean the old build.

second commend `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed Elsayed  
the problem solved 
 the Steps to solve this problem it :
-1 replace the SDK from stable to dev 
-2 in termenal I execute this commends 
first commend `flutter clean` to clean the old build 
second commend `flutter pub cache repair`
-3 finally I run the project and it run well

Answer (score 0):

I used a Github Actions workflow to build the apk. Had the same issue but changed the channel from `stable` to `beta` to setup my flutter and everything worked fine.

```
- name: Setup Flutter
  uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
  with:
     channel: "beta"
```